# Flexbox taking up full width on iOS16 (Iphone 14 pro max) but working fine everywhere else

Tags: css, responsive-design

I've recently learned responsive web designing and now I'm stuck with a weird issue on iphone 14 pro max. The text in the

& the contact form takes up 100% width instead of inheriting the width of the parent element. Below is the screenshot & the website

website - shesharma.com

I'm not sure what is happening. I've looked at my media queries and the css looks fine. Do I have to use vendor specific css? Please suggest me the best way to get around this.

[image]

[image]

I'm using flexbox model to make the website responsive and all the padding, width, margins & fonts are in rem. In the entire css, there are no vendor specific css so I guess adding some might help. However, I don't know which one.

- Media Queries - https://shesharma.com/css/queries.css
- Main CSS - https://shesharma.com/css/styles.css
- Class in Concern - hero-text & get-in-touch (all child element)

I've tried to remove the padding from both these classes, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.